# Friendly URL for a Page

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-navigation

I need to know how to set a friendly URL for a page. I have other pages with where this is working but I can't seem to find where it is set on the page properties.

```
mydomain.com/Pages/myPage.aspx -> mydomain.com/myPage
```

Comment: It is set in the term  store. Google for more info. You will find a lot of results.

Comment: not using the term store here. I've done this before where its simply setting a friendly URL to a page. No terms but I can't seem to find the property anymore.

Comment: Right. I assumed you were using managed navigation. I'm not sure how you could do this without managed navigation. I think this is the only way. Let's see if someone else has another way :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a button under the Page tab of the Ribbon labeled "Page URLs", which is where you go to specify which term(s) point(s) to a given page.

[image: Use the Page URLs button to configure friendly URLs for a page]

In order to use this, you must first set up the following:

1. Have a Managed Metadata service running in the farm
2. Create a term set for Site Navigation in the MM Term Store
3. Configure the Intended Use setting of the Term Set to Site Navigation
   [image: Configure the Term Set for Site Navigation]
4. Populate the Term Set with terms representing navigational nodes
5. Configure the site to use Managed Navigation (not structural) for either Global or Current navigation, and select the Term Set from Step 2 as the source.
   [image]

Once you have done these things, you should be able to click on the Page URL's button and then assign it a term from the above Term Set, which will then become its "Friendly" url. 
[image]
[image]

This is a very broad overview of the process, and there are a lot of other possible configuration steps you can follow. For a more detailed tutorial, see the following page on Microsoft Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/stage-8-assign-a-category-page-and-a-catalog-item-page-to-a-term

If your site navigation is configured to create friendly url's automatically, then it will do the same process as above in the background when you create a new page.

Also, once you have assigned a Term to a page, you can edit it in two ways: 
 1. Modify the *term* itself in the Term Store
 2. Click the *Page URLs* button to change term assignments for a given page.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the `Add A Page` link from the Gear menu. I couldn't edit the Friendly URL from the Page Properties.